# Checkpoint mobile vpn

Tags: linux, vpn, checkpoint

I am using a VPN provided by my university. I connected to the VPN on ubuntu 22.04.1 using https://github.com/ruyrybeyro/chrootvpn but the problem that I am facing is that the traffic is not being routed through the VPN interface.

Comment: I'd suggest to open a new issue on project's page: https://github.com/ruyrybeyro/chrootvpn/issues

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: @AlexLipov The "issue" was it is a full tunnel VPN configuration without direct Internet access. Rather common configuration in corporate, not so much in a University setting. The user discovered alone how to work around it.